# How to set a global variable in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

Ok, so I've been looking around for around 40 minutes for how to set a global variable on Python, and all the results I got were complicated and advanced questions and more so answers.
I'm trying to make a slot machine in Python, and I want to make a coins system, where you can actually earn coins so the game is better, but when I ran the code, it told me 'UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment'. I made my variable global, by putting:

```
global coins

coins = 50
```

which for some reason printed '50' and gave the UnboundLocalError error again, so from one answer I tried:

```
def GlobalCoins():    
    global coins      
    coins = 50
```

which, despite the following error, didn't print '50': 'NameError: global name 'coins' is not defined'. 
Soo I don't really know how to set one. 
This is probably extremely basic stuff and this is probably also a duplicate question, but my web searches and attempts in-program have proved fruitless, so I'm in the doldrums for now.

Comment: Did you put both those pieces of code in the same file?  Your code doesn't print anything, so why do you expect it to product any output?

Comment: You need to declare coins and then when you want to change it declare it global.

Comment: Thank you so much, this finally works now. thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Omit the 'global' keyword in the declaration of coins outside the function. [This article](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php) provides a good survey of globals in Python. For example, this code:

```
def f():
    global s
    print s
    s = "That's clear."
    print s 


s = "Python is great!" 
f()
print s
```

outputs this:

```
Python is great!
That's clear.
That's clear.
```

The 'global' keyword does not create a global variable. It is used to pull in a variable that already exists outside of its scope.

Comment: It's true that `global` itself doesn't create the variable, but it doesn't require that it already exist either.  Inside a function, you can do `global x` and then `x = 10` and that will create the global variable if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As @BrenBarn says, you can create a global variable. The reason why the last output is not "Python is great!" is because the global variable inside the function, s, has already been assigned a new value "That's clear."